# writing in a special place of a text file using php

Tags: php

I have a text file :

```
//IT IS A PRIVATE FILE
//
First Name :
//
Last Name :
///////////
```

I receive first name and last name from a php form which based on POST method. After that I want to write first name in front of `First Name :` and last name in front of `Last Name :`
but I can't do that ! please help. by the way this script must be in php.

```
<form action="page2.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="text" name="lname">
</form>
```

If you want more details please ask and I will tell you.

Comment: By "I can't do that" do you mean you haven't tried to do it?  If you have tried, can you show what you have so far?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good at English!

Comment: It's not about being good at english or not, it's about being courteous when asking a question. As written, it sounds like you want us to just provide the answer. Instead, include **what you tried** and **why it didn't work**

Comment: @user3165410 Show the code you have so far and explain specifically what is not working as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

[fseek()](http://www.php.net/fseek) let's you jump to an address in a file. Then you could make updates with [fwrite()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php).

But that's not what you want. You're looking for an insert function similar to the behaviour of text editors. There is no such function. You have to read the file content, make your edits and **overwrite** the file with the new content. PHP offers sufficent [filesystem functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) for that task.